# UINavigationBar title font size in landscape

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uifont, uiappearance

Is there anyway I can set the font size for the `UINavigationBar` title in landscape mode?

I'm using the `UIAppearance` proxy to customize the title text attributes and I am specifically interested in the font size when in landscape. It's font in portrait but when rotating to landscape the font size does not shrink as the default behaviour.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"Awesome-Bold" size:20], UITextAttributeFont,
                                           [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.2f], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                           [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, -1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                           [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                           nil]];
```

Unfortunately I don't see any `barMetric:` property to go along with `setTitleAttributes:`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So after researching a bit online [I find out](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) the font size has to be set to `0` which ensures the font is automatically set to the appropriate size in landscape and portrait:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Awesome-Bold" size:0], UITextAttributeFont
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Where did you put this code?

Comment: It's part of the dictionary that is set above in `setTitleTextAttributes:`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't make myself clear -- I mean where in the app is the entire block of code that you posted? viewDiLoad? init? I've tried it all over the place, and I see no effect.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I usually customize my app's appearance in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I generally make a separate method `-(void)customizeAppearance` that I then call from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Hope that helps.